# Cannot resolve method display(int)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

the main_activity code below seems logically correct but shows a compiler error

```
package com.example.android.cricketcount;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.lang.Object;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        int scoreTeamA = 0;
        int scoreTeamB = 0;


        public void add6(View){
            scoreTeamA = scoreTeamA + 6:
        display(scoreTeamA);
        }

        public void add4(View){
                scoreTeamA = scoreTeamA + 4:
        display(scoreTeamA);
        }
    }
}
```

while executing the code it shows that it suffered from a compilation error

Comment: Where is that `display()` function? I don't see that function defined